# Moving angularJS site to Visual Studio?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

So in my quest to learn front-end development (doing server side, WCF, etc for the past 4-5 years), I managed to create a simple little movie app just using javascript and html. When I created this app, I was using Sublime Text and since I'm a .NET developer, I'd like to move this site over to Visual Studio and actually wire it up to WebAPI or MVC and start talking to a database.

What is the best way to move over a pure html/javascript/css site into Visual Studio and wiring it up for db connectivity? I thought about just creating a web site project in a solution and start wiring it up to a BLL and DAL layer but I didn't know if that was ideal or not.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Just for clarification, do you want to also code in Visual Studio or is the main concern being able to talk to your back-end from your Angular app?

Comment: @yvesmancera Correct. I'd like to be able to code in Visual Studio as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO Your best bet is to create an empty WebAPi2 project in VS and create a folder called 'app' that you will move your Angular files into.

Right click your project and go to the Web tab. Set the start page to whatever HTML file is your main page.

You should now be able to just F5 and run the application. Then start creating WebApi controllers for your data layer and you should just able to hit the API from localhost/api (or whatever you designate in your routes)

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS should be completely independent of the server language (php, c#) and server (nginx, apache, IIS) you run it on.

I have worked on angular projects that talk to C# WCF services and are hosted on IIS just fine.  You best bet is to create restful services in WCF and use angular services and factories to pull that data into the client angular app.

I think the best place to start would be the $http service of Angularjs.
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http